# How can I access NVIDIA control panel

Tags: nvidia, software-installation, gpu, minecraft

I just got Ubuntu two weeks ago. I installed the game Minecraft using Openjdk 7 runtime. It's laggy (it was on Windows too) until I did one thing. On Windows I would right click my desktop and click NVIDIA Control Panel and then I would change the 3D graphics or something like that to performance. Can you tell me how to access NVIDIA control panel on Ubuntu?
Thanks.

I am running Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit

Comment: Can I ask how you did this on your machine? When using the nvidia settings on ubuntu I see no 3D graphics area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install nvidia-settings :

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates nvidia-settings-updates
```

Then In terminal :

```
gksu nvidia-settings
```

Type your password .